# httphandlers in azure 500 internal server error

Tags: azure, ihttphandler, azure-web-roles

I am not able to work with htpphandlers in azure after deploy, it is ok with in the local machine.

In web.config I declared as follows

```
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.cspx" type="WebRole1.Handle,WebRole1"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

In my handler.cs file i written as follows.

```
namespace WebRole1
```

{
    public class Handle : IHttpHandler
    {
        #region IHttpHandler Members

```
    bool IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Server.Transfer("Test.aspx", true);         
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

In my local machine it is working fine. But after deploy to windows azure getting 
500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related with having custom handlers in system.web instead of system.webserver.

Move your custom HTTP Handler to System.webserver as below:

```
<system.webserver>
 <httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.cspx" type="WebRole1.Handle,WebRole1"/>
</httpHandlers>
<system.webserver>
```